# Blank layout - eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I am constantly recieving the following message: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented I tried cleaning the project, played around with manifest, search others who had similar issue s but my attempt have been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my activity code

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

public class LoadImg extends Activity  {
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);
        save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        String picturePath = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("picturePath", "");
        if(!picturePath.equals(""))
        {
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }        
        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });        
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Locate the image in res > 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("picturePath");
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                Object image = null;
                try {
                    String path = null;
                    image = readInFile(path);
                }
                catch(Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("picturePath", (byte[]) image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveInBackground();

                // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
                ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("Image");

                // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                imgupload.put("Image", "picturePath");


                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

                // Create the class and the columns
                imgupload.saveInBackground();

                // Show a simple toast message
                Toast.makeText(LoadImg.this, "Image Saved, Upload another one ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }

    private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] data = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
        }
        input_stream.close();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

    }}}
```

Below is the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dooba.beta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.dooba.beta.IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.UserDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.EventsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.MoodActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mood"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_creation" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and below is the layout file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white_blue"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:textColor="#000000" >

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio0"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:checked="true"
                 android:text="Male"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Female"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="No response"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />
         </RadioGroup>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Profile Creation"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="22sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
             android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
             android:text="Search Distance (100KM)"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             android:textColor="#000000" />

         <SeekBar
             android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="35dp"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
             android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
             android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
             android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
             android:text="Profile Picture"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:onClick="uploadPhoto"
             android:text="Confirm" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_above="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
             android:onClick="pickPhoto"
             android:text="Select photo"
             android:textSize="15sp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
             android:text="Small Text"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
             android:ems="10"
             android:hint="Username / Peferred Name"
             android:inputType="textPersonName"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16sp" >

             <requestFocus />
         </EditText>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
             android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
             android:text="I am a"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup2"
             android:text="Looking for"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
             android:ems="10"
             android:inputType="number" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView7"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
             android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
             android:text="Age"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textSize="16sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
             android:layout_width="150dp"
             android:layout_height="120dp"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnConfirm"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.90"
             android:alpha="0.8"
             android:background="#d2d2d2" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="100dp"
             android:layout_height="70dp"
             android:layout_above="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
             android:text="Upload from Facebook"
             android:textSize="15sp" />

         <RadioGroup
             android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1" >

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio0"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:checked="true"
                 android:text="Male"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Female"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />

             <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="No response"
                 android:textColor="#000000" />
         </RadioGroup>

     </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Update**
Error shown in logcat. Layout now shows, but eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented error remains.

```
  07-28 00:54:11.288: D/dalvikvm(1248): Late-enabling CheckJNI
    07-28 00:54:11.484: D/dalvikvm(1248): GC_CONCURRENT freed 255K, 11% free 3088K/3456K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 15ms
    07-28 00:54:11.484: D/dalvikvm(1248): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
    07-28 00:54:11.484: I/dalvikvm-heap(1248): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.198MB for 1127532-byte allocation
    07-28 00:54:11.488: D/dalvikvm(1248): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 4189K/4560K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
    07-28 00:54:11.592: I/jdwp(1248): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
    07-28 00:54:11.600: D/dalvikvm(1248): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 7% free 4480K/4800K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
    07-28 00:54:11.804: D/libEGL(1248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
    07-28 00:54:11.804: D/(1248): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7985ee8, tid 1248
    07-28 00:54:11.820: D/libEGL(1248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
    07-28 00:54:11.820: D/libEGL(1248): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
    07-28 00:54:11.868: W/EGL_genymotion(1248): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    07-28 00:54:11.868: E/OpenGLRenderer(1248): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
    07-28 00:54:11.872: E/OpenGLRenderer(1248): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
    07-28 00:54:11.876: E/OpenGLRenderer(1248): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
    07-28 00:54:11.876: E/OpenGLRenderer(1248): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
    07-28 00:54:11.876: D/OpenGLRenderer(1248): Enabling debug mode 0
    07-28 00:54:24.612: I/jdwp(1248): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
    07-28 00:54:24.788: I/jdwp(1248): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
    07-28 00:54:36.984: I/jdwp(1248): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
    07-28 00:54:37.576: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1248): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    07-28 00:54:42.984: W/EGL_genymotion(1248): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    07-28 00:54:43.744: W/ViewRootImpl(1248): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=65685, downTime=65685, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
    07-28 00:54:43.744: W/ViewRootImpl(1248): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=65859, downTime=65859, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
    07-28 00:54:43.752: W/ViewRootImpl(1248): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=66028, downTime=66028, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
    07-28 00:54:43.760: W/ViewRootImpl(1248): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=66186, downTime=66186, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
    07-28 00:54:44.320: I/jdwp(1248): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
```

Comment: You cannot see anything in your layout?

Comment: Bro, its completely blank, and this is complety unusual. I tried running a different version of the emulator.

Comment: What is your drawable white_blue? Is it simply a background color?

Comment: Is it blank in every emulator/devices?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The drawable white_blue is a background image that looks completly fine on eclipse device preview but when loaded on multiple emulators, along with my actual android device, the screen is completely gray with no text field, or input shown, which is odd since the items are clearly visible in eclipse device preview.

Comment: You don't get any error/exception on your LogCat, besides that one?

Comment: Where do you see this error? Is it a compile error or a runtime one? What API version do you use in your emu?

Comment: Why do you have LoadImg as an internal class for ProfileCreation? That is why you are not getting anything as your layout.

Comment: Thanks man. I realized I was accidenly declaring two activities. I believe to have fix the issue, and I did and now I am able to see the activity, but I am still getting the eglsurfaceattr error. I think it occurs when a user click the select photo button, that is suppose to grab an image from the gallery (which it does), but it is also suppose to show that image in the imageview, which doesn't and return the error shown in the code I have placed under my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring two Activities in your File: `ProfileCreation` and `LoadImg` . Only the latter has its`onCreate()` method defined. But `Android` searches for the `ProfileCreation` `onCreate()` method and does not find it. So, it does not draw your layout. Remove one of the Activities declaration. I also noticed that LoadImg Activity is not defined at your manifest.xml file.

Edit: You are starting your `ACTION_PICK Intent` with `startActivityForResult()`. For receiving the result of that `Intent`, you must override `onActivityResult()` method, so you can handle the picked Image info from the Gallery.

Comment: Thanks man for making me realize that I accidentally declaring two activities. I believe to have fix the issue, and I did and now I am able to see the activity, but I am still getting the eglsurfaceattr error. I think it occurs when a user click the select photo button, that is suppose to grab an image from the gallery (which it does), but it is also suppose to show that image in the imageview, which doesn't and return the error shown in the code I have placed under my initial post.

Comment: I think that error message is related with Genymotion. You should investigate.

Comment: You are starting you PICK Intent with `startActivityForResult()`. Are you overriding `onACtivityResult()` to handle the Intent callback?

Comment: I tried on my phone as well, and the issue still present. onActivityResult is not included; just make reference to startActivityForResult

Comment: Without onActivityResult() you will never receive the picked Image from the Gallery.  See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html for learning how to use it.

Comment: Thanks man onActivityResult section was all that I was missing. I got it to work on geny, and I am assuming should be fine on my phone.

Comment: Good, I will update my answer with that information. Feel free to upvote it if you want.