# Performing stop of activity that is not resumed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am making a simple Android app just to become familiar with the concept. I have an app with two activities, the first should just be a splash screen that displays for one second, the second is a canvas w/ a black square that turns cyan when you click it. When I run it, it stops with an error in the log saying "performing stop of activity that is not resumed".

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        Intent in = new Intent(this, Afspl.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Next Activity:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Afspl extends Activity {

    public DrawView vi;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        vi = new DrawView(this);
    }

    class DrawView extends View{
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c){
            paint.setColor(col);
            c.drawRect(40, 40, 200, 200, paint);

        }

        private int col = Color.BLACK;

        public void setToColor(int c){
            col=c;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        if(me.getX()>=30 &&  me.getX() <= 320 && me.getY() >=30 && me.getY() <= 320)vi.setToColor(Color.CYAN);
        return super.onTouchEvent(me);
    }


}
```

Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error or what it means or how I can fix this? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your thread is in a sleeping state when it tries to stop (since you called startActivity while it is waiting). You are trying to stop it, but it isn't currently in a resumed state.

Comment: If I use a Handler which puts a run function in a runnable class, how do I refer to the MainActivity class in which the Handler is, as 'this' will refer to the runnable?

Comment: If you're learning, then switch your approach and do not do a splash screen.  They are anti Android and users hate them.  Do you expect to see a splash screen on a web page?  What happens when you hit a web page and they show you and advertising dialog that you must pass before you can use the page?  Sucks doesn't it?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand how to switch between Activities, for the app I'm making, this seemed like a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insted of using:

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}catch(Exception e){}
Intent in = new Intent(this, Afspl.class);
startActivity(in);
```

You could try using new

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Afspl.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
}, 1000);
```

You should never put to sleep the main thread. If you want to do something in the future use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Also, you should declare a View on both Activities, not just the first one. Create a View and set it with "setContentView()" on your second activity.

Comment: Like this, 'this' in the Intent constructor will be the runnable not the MainActivity. How do I refer to the MainActivity instead?

Comment: @user2649681 instead of using this, use MainActivity.this

Comment: @user2649681 this will be the MainActivity, not the Runnable. Did you try the code?

Comment: Now the app can start up w/o an error, but i just get a blank gray screen, what I'd expect for the main activity, but the other activity never loads, and I get failed to set egl_swap_behavior in the log. Do you know what that is?

Comment: @Storo
Intent doesn't take Runnable as an argument.

Comment: @user2649681 You were right. My mistake. Change "this" for "getApplicationContext()"

Comment: Do you know how I can fix the eglsurfaceattrib not implemented?

Comment: @user2649681 First, did it load the second activity? Regarding the eglsurfaceattrib not implemented, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986930/blank-layout-eglsurfaceattrib-not-implemented) Also, shouldn't you also use "setContentView(...);" on the second activity? You never set it's View.

Comment: But I have onCreate on both activities. It leaves the first activity, but nothing appears on the second activity, it's just a blank screen.
How would I setContentView? Sorry, I'm new to this, what should I set it to, I mean?
EDIT: Oh wait I see what you mean for the contentview let me try something.

Comment: @user2649681 Thats because you didn't use "setContentView()", check the following [link] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Ok, now I've setContentView(), but the apk fails to install on the emulator altogether now. Any ideas why?

Comment: Shouldn't you first mark the question as correct, since it solved your problem? ("performing stop of activity that is not resumed"). I'm glad to help but that is a topic for another question. We can move the discussion to a Chat to keep this question clean.

Comment: Right, right. Anyway I figured out the rest, thank you for your help, I would never have thought to use a Handler.